# How to solve java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have written the below query in a repository class to retrieve the records having different deal_no (deal number), but as there are more than 1000 records in the table, I am getting below error.

FYI, `dealNoChunkList` is the list containing more than 1000 deal numbers.

```java
List<List<String>> dealNoChunkList = Lists.partition(dealNoList, 100);
where dealNoList =[3817,3456,7898.............]    (having more than 1000 records)
```

**AppImpl.java**

```java
for(List<String> deal_no : dealNoChunkList)
{
List<Deal> chunkUFList = underlyingFundsRepo.findByItemIdList(deal_no);
ufList.addAll(chunkUFList);
}
```

**AppRepo.java**

```
@Query("FROM Deal uf WHERE uf.itemId IN (?1)")
public List<Deal> findByItemIdList(List<String> dealNumberList);
```

Error StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
..
..
..
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 255
```

Comment: Can you _edit_ your question and reveal the source of the `dealNoChunkList` list?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , added the asked resource in above Added Section